# scanimage on ADF not working with --batch

Tags: scanner, scanning, multi-function-printer, document-scanning, xsane

I want to scan multiple file with an ADF.

This is my device:

```
luca@luca-server:~$ sudo scanimage -L
device `xerox_mfp:libusb:001:006' is a Samsung SCX-3400 Series multi-function peripheral
```

If I run this command:

```
luca@luca-server:~$ sudo scanimage --batch --format=tiff
```

It scans correctly the first page on the ADF.
But then it flushes all the other pages!
This is the output on a test with three pages on the ADF:

```
luca@luca-server:~$ sudo scanimage --batch --format=tiff
Scanning -1 pages, incrementing by 1, numbering from 1
Scanning page 1
Scanned page 1. (scanner status = 5)
Scanning page 2
scanimage: sane_start: Operation was cancelled
```

The --batch-prompt option does not solve the problem because it only says that the ADF is empty on the next page that has to be scanned. (Because it flushed all the pages after the first scan)

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

scanimage --source ADF --device-name=$device --resolution $resolution --mode $mode --format=tiff --batch=scans/out%d.tiff --batch-start=10

worked for me

Comment: --batch-start=10 <--- for better sorting